# Downloading a file with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to download a file so the users have the option of opening or saving.  They click the file name:

```
<a href data-ng-click="getFile(file.id)">
                    {{file.name}}</span>
                </a>
```

Then this calls a method in the angular js file

```
$scope.getFile= function ($id) {
    var getInputFilePromise = fileFactory.getInputFile($id);
    getFilePromise.success(function ($data) {
        var blob = new Blob([$data], {type: 'text/csv'});
        //code to allow downloading file
});
}
```

The factory has the following code to get the byte[] from the java controller:

```
getFile: function ($id) {
        return $http.get('/downloadFile?id=' + $id, {responseType:'arraybuffer'});
    }
```

As you can see from my getFile method I convert the data to a blob but I am unable to send this to the html.  I have tried numerous solutions posted on here but none have worked.

```
var blob = new Blob([$data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
```

The above code snippet allows for a file to be downloaded but Excel cant open it.

Any help would be great as I am new to angular.  I would also like to avoid using FileSaver.js

I have also tried the following but it does not work.

```
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/csv,' + encodeURI($data);
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = fileName;
            hiddenElement.click();
```

Comment: you can use this  <a href="/images/aaa.jpg" download>

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this, in the first lines of your getFile method:

```
var fileName = "outputfile.pdf";
var a = document.createElement("a");
```

And in your success:

```
getFilePromise.success(function ($data) {
    var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.href = fileURL;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
}
```